# What does the skill "Knowledge (any)" mean?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, dnd-3e

In Dungeons and Dragons, my character is a Bard Elf. I have the Bard Starting Package, which includes four starting skills (I can only choose 4 due to modifiers) But after "Knowledge", in parentheses it says "any". Context:

> Knowledge (any)   Rank 4   Ability Int

Does "any" mean I can choose any kind of knowledge from the skill descriptions, or that I already know all of the knowledge sets? I'm new to D&D so the book I am using may be a bit old and I am still learning.

Comment: You could greatly improve the question by specifying the D&D edition. It should be found in the small print near the front cover.

Comment: This is the same in 3.0 and 3.5, so it doesn't really matter. Tagging with both for now.

Comment: It means your bard is omniscient and probably has at least 1 divine ranks :P

Answer (score 16):

On page 30 of the *D&D 3.5 Player's Handbook*, the bard starting package lists:

> Knowledge (any **one**) | Rank 4 | Ability Int

(my emphasis)

Knowledge ("any" or "any one") is sometimes used as a shorthand for the ability to select any of the game's Knowledge skills (listed under the skills section in the book and -- if you're playing D&D 3.5 -- listed [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/knowledge.htm)). Contrast it with the [Druid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm), who can select Knowledge (nature) but not any of the other Knowledge skills.

If a bard has six skills to choose, she can have from zero to all six of them be knowledge skills. For example a bard with six skills to choose might choose Knowledge (arcana), Knowlege (religion), and Knowledge (local), leaving three additional skills to select.

Note also that by default in D&D 3.0 and 3.5 one puts four ranks in whatever skills they choose at 1st level, which is why you see "Ranks 4" next to each skill in the starting package.